# Pygame get color of pixel where cursor is located

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

How can I get the color of the pixel directly under the pointer in pygame?

I have done a lot of research, but the answer is rather shy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the surface of the screen created with `pygame.display.set_mode` is `surface`  then you can do this:

```
color = surface.get_at(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) # get the color of pixel at mouse position
```

Answer (score 0):

@Malik's answer is very correct. And here is a working demo:

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode( (200, 200) )
last_color = None

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    surface.fill( (0,0,255) )
    pygame.draw.rect( surface, (255,0,0), (0, 0, 100, 100) )
    pygame.draw.rect( surface, (0,255,0), (100, 100, 100, 100) )

    color = surface.get_at(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) 
    if last_color != color:
        print(color)
        last_color = color

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```